# non-unary coefficient in trinom formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that the trinomial formula for factorization when the coefficient for $x^2$ is $1$ is as follows:

$x^2 + bx + c = (x+x_1)(x+x_2)$
$s.t.:$

$x_1 + x_2 = b$ $and$  $x_1 \cdot x_2 = c$

Could anyone explain what changes when $a \neq 1$? How will this affect the factorization?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Did you mean $a\neq1$?

Comment: Regardless, you can simply just factor out the $a$ and apply the normal factorisation: $ax^2+bx+c=a(x^2+(b/a)x+(c/a))=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ where $x_1,x_2$ are roots

Comment: Thanks FShrike!

Comment: A polynomial in which the leading coefficient is $1$ is called *monic*.  If you wish to factor a nonmonic quadratic polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$ with integer coefficients, you want to find two integers with product $ac$ and sum $b$.  For instance, to factor $9x^2 + 6x - 8$, we must find two numbers with product $9(-8) = -72$ and sum $6$.  They are $-6$ and $12$.  Splitting the linear term and grouping yields \begin{align*} 9x^2 + 6x - 8 & = 9x^2 - 6x + 12x - 8 \\ & = 3x(3x - 2) + 4(3x - 2)\\ & = (3x + 4)(3x - 2) \end{align*}